# Using binary search tree with custom data types?

Tags: haskell, recursive-datastructures

I've create a binary search tree:

```
data SearchTree a = Empty | Node a (SearchTree a) (SearchTree a) deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

insertTreeElements :: (Ord a) => a -> SearchTree a -> SearchTree a --Create    binary tree input method
insertTreeElements x Empty = Node x Empty Empty
insertTreeElements x (Node a left right)
   | x == a     = Node x left right
   | x < a  = Node a (insertTreeElements x left) right
   | x > a      = Node a left (insertTreeElements x right)

makeTree :: (Ord a) => (a -> SearchTree a -> SearchTree a) -> SearchTree a -> [a] -> SearchTree a --Create binary tree
makeTree iTE Empty li = foldr iTE Empty li
```

I'm trying to pass in the following list:

```
Type Age = Int
mylist = [Age 12, Age 100, Age 2, Age 3, Age 43]
```

However the output is not correct, it does not order the tree based on the size of the ages? How do I need to edit the insertTreeElements to allow it to work with 'Age x'?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the biggest problem you have is this one:

```
   | x > a      = Node a left (insertTreeElements x left)
```

Notice that you write `left` twice -- presumably one of them should be `right`.